# Передача параметра из Vue

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, vue.js

Не моу передать значения из фреймворка Vue в MVC или HTML атрибуту **href**, (он воспринимает это как название com.IDUser и не как иначе) есть ссылка

```
<a class="button_message" v-bind:id="'button_message' + com.IDUser" href="/Manage/ViewActivity?nameButtonExe=%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5&amp;IdUser=com.IDUser" role="button" onclick="MessageComment(this)">Сообщение</a>
```

Такая переда работает (переменная берется из цикла v-for="com in comments")

```
v-bind:id="'button_message' + com.IDUser"
```

Но в **href="/Manage/ViewActivity?.......**
Категорически нет, хоть так com.IDUser или {{com.IDUser}} не имеет значения не работает, а при v-bind:href вообще вылетает в ошибку. Помогите передать значения в переменные  **href=**

Answer (score 0):

```
<a :href=`/Manage/ViewActivity?nameButtonExe=%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5&amp;IdUser=${com.IDUser}` role="button" onclick="MessageComment(this)">Сообщение</a>
```

обратите внимание на кавычки. Они такие не случайно

Comment: Не так пробовал, при любом изменении  :href или v-bind:href выдает ошибку Error compiling template: invalid expression: Invalid regular expression flags in

Comment: видимо `/Manage/` воспринимается как регулярное выражение. Экранируйте слэши

Comment: Не получается може вы приведите конкретный пример

Comment: Работает спасибо <a id="button_message7f01196d-3f72-403c-8d58-acdf1766c667" href="/Manage/ViewActivity?nameButtonExe=Сообщение&amp;IdUser=7f01196d-3f72-403c-8d58-acdf1766c667" role="button" class="button_message">Сообщение</a>